Multiple imeActions on TextField in Jetpack Compose
In Jetpack Compose I want to handle multiple imeAction events in a TextField. I want the enter key to both create a new line and move to other TextFields. In many applications, this is shown in the small menu that appears when the enter key is long pressed.
Because only one imeAction parameter can be passed, the operations in keyboardActions do not work.
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    var tf1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var tf2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp,Alignment.CenterVertically)
    ) {
        TextField(value = tf1, onValueChange = {tf1 = it})

        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            keyboardOptions =
                KeyboardOptions(
                    // I want to use Default, Previous and Next imeActions in this TextField.
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Default,
                ),
            singleLine = false,
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onPrevious = {
                    defaultKeyboardAction(
                        ImeAction.Previous
                    )
                },
                onNext = {
                    defaultKeyboardAction(
                        ImeAction.Next
                    )
                }
            )
        )

        TextField(value = tf2, onValueChange = {tf2 = it})
    }
}


